# How to retrieve the field values from model objects

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model which contains `2` List Field's:

```
class Cimex_Search(models.Model):
    search_engine = ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True),blank=True,null=True,default=list)
    web_technology = ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True),blank=True,null=True,default=list)

    def __str__(self):
        return "default"
```

Now I have the following function in views.py:

```
def cimex_search_searcher(request):
        default_table = Cimex_Search.objects.get(id=1)
        field_type = request.GET.get('fieldtype')
        print(default_table.field_type) ###! NEED HELP HERE
```

- How to pass the `fieldtype` value to the `Model Object`?
- I Would like to retrieve the model object list based on the `fieldtype` input parameter value.

What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `getattr` passing the model and field, so for your use case that would be:

```
def cimex_search_searcher(request):
    default_table = Cimex_Search.objects.get(id=1)
    field_type = request.GET.get('fieldtype')
    print(getattr(default_table, field_type))
```

Comment: What if I have to update the `field_type` field value ?  something like this `ex: `field_value = ["google.com","facebook.com"]; field_value.save()`  , How to do this?

Comment: In that case you can use `setattr`, it works the same way. `setattr(object, name, value)`